# Could not HEAD libvlc

Tags: android

When building my project I get this errorL

```
Could not HEAD 'https://dl.bintray.com/videolan/Android/de/mrmaffen/libvlc-android/2.1.12/libvlc-android-2.1.12.pom'. Received status code 502 from server: Bad Gateway
Disable Gradle 'offline mode' and sync project
```

Gradle is in online mode.

this is my build.gradle(app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "windylabs.com.vlcplayersample"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
//    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
    compile 'de.mrmaffen:libvlc-android:2.1.12@aar'
//    implementation "de.mrmaffen:vlc-android-sdk:1.0.6"
}
```

Comment: The vlc library you are using is unofficial and probably obsolete. Try using the official library. You may refer to [this article](https://nphau.medium.com/android-how-to-embed-vlc-media-player-to-android-app-1828d34c54f)

Answer (score 0):

The error message already stated that you should `Disable Gradle 'offline mode' and sync project`. Navigate to the gradle window at View > Tool Windows > Gradle. Click the [image] **Toggle Offline Mode** button near the top of the Gradle window to disable `offline mode`.

Comment: That was the first thing I did Sir and I get a 502.